# how to stop and start renderer in java swing

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, renderer, thread-priority

renderer gives me error  while column sorting  because of column index.renderer paints columns  according to columns value so ı should keep renderer waiting during column sorter is working. How can I do?

Comment: For better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). You probably have something that is not coded correctly. You don't need to prevent painting during sorting events (although I don't see how both can occur simultaneously without multiple threads which is not supported by Swing, btw).

Comment: I would suggest you need to use `convertRowIndexToView()` or `convertRowIndexToModel()` somewhere in your code.